# Why my binary file is not larger when loading a static library

Tags: android, android-ndk

Here is my Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libdict

LOCAL_MODULE := test_demo

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I change `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` to `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, `test_demo` is the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ linker will trim the unused functions of library. So if you don't use the function of libdict or only use some very simple functions, the size of your binary file will not increase significantly.

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted my test example, and got the expected result.